# Asymmetric Random Walk / Prove that $E[T:= \inf\{n: X_n = b\}] < \infty$

Tags: stochastic-processes, probability, martingale, random-walk, stopping

Given random variables $Y_1, Y_2, ... \stackrel{iid}{\sim} P(Y_i = 1) = p = 1 - q = 1 - P(Y_i = -1)$ where $p > q$ in a filtered probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$ where $\mathscr F_n = \mathscr F_n^Y$,

define $X = (X_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $X_0 = 0$ and $X_n = \sum_{i=1}^{n} Y_i$.

It can be shown that the stochastic process $M = (M_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $M_n = X_n - n(p-q)$ is a $(\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}, \mathbb P)$-martingale.

Let $b$ be a positive integer and $T:= \inf\{n: X_n = b\}$.

It can be shown that $T$ is a $\{\mathscr F_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$-stopping time.

Prove that $E[T] < \infty$.

One proposition to use is '[What always stands a reasonable chance of happening will (almost surely) happen - sooner rather than later](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=e9saZ0YSi-AC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=%22what%20always%20stands%22%20%22probability%22&source=bl&ots=AWEio5s6Xq&sig=6kAyfQZorHRSFhYEVjQ83V7XGU4&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwje6t-I0MTJAhUleaYKHUa7AfIQ6AEIGjAA#v=onepage&q=%22what%20always%20stands%22%20%22probability%22&f=false)' or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1468800/140308) (proof [here](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~ps422/Solution_1_Vittoria.pdf))

So let us show either that $\exists N \in \mathbb N, \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb N$,

$$P(T \le n + N | \mathscr F_n) > \epsilon$$

or the weaker condition that $\exists N \in \mathbb N, \epsilon > 0$ s.t. $\forall n \in \mathbb N$,

$$P(T > kN) \le (1 - \epsilon)^k$$

---

I tried the first one:

$$P(T \le \infty | \mathscr F_n) = E(1_{T \le \infty} | \mathscr F_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{T=i} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{\infty} E[1_{T=i} | \mathscr F_n]$$

Hence, we must find and integer N and a positive number $\epsilon$ s.t.

$$P(T \le n + N | \mathscr F_n) = E(1_{T \le n + N} | \mathscr F_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1_{T=i} + \sum_{i=n+1}^{n+N} E[1_{T=i} | \mathscr F_n] > \epsilon$$

where $\forall i > n$,

$$E[1_{T=i} | \mathscr F_n] = P(T=i | \mathscr F_n)$$

$$= P(X_i = b, X_1 \ne b, X_2 \ne b, ..., X_n \ne b, ..., X_{i-1} \ne b | \mathscr F_n)$$

$$= \prod_{j=1}^{n} 1_{X_j \ne b} E[1_{X_i = b} \prod_{j=n+1}^{i-1} 1_{X_j \ne b} | \mathscr F_n]$$

---

That's all I got. How can I approach this problem?

Comment: From where did you take this problem?

Comment: @james42 previous exam in my university

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\because M_n$ is a martingale and $T \wedge k$ is bounded, by Doob's optional stopping theorem, we have

$$E[M_{T \wedge k}] = E[M_0] = 0$$

$$\to E[T \wedge k] = \frac{1}{p-q} E[X_{T \wedge k}]$$

By monotone convergence theorem, we have

$$E[T] = \lim_{k \to \infty} E[T \wedge k]$$

Finally, by definition of $T$, we have

$$X_{T \wedge k} \le \frac{b}{p-q}$$

$$\to E[T] \le \frac{b}{p-q} < \infty \ QED$$

Comment: If you can provide more details, it will be more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Let $b=1$, $p=1/3$, $q=2/3$. It is [not hard to show](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153123/biased-random-walk-on-line) that in this case $T$ is finite with probability exactly $1/2$. Consequently, $E[T] = \infty$ and your claim does not hold in general.

The claim would hold if $p\geq q$ (in which case you could, for example, address it by first showing that it holds for $b=1$ and proceeding inductively from there on).

Comment: The induction would easily get you that P(T is finite) = 1. It immediately follows that E[T] is finite, although I could not point you to the relevant theorem off the top of my head right now.

Comment: Huh? If T is infinite, its expectation is infinite. Right?

Comment: Wait actually induction on what? Should I still use the proposition in the Williams book?

Comment: That proposition is something that may help you connect P(T is finite) = 1 to E[T] is finite. You would still need to show that P(T is finite) = 1. That one is easily shown by observing that with probability one T will move one step up (i.e. solve for b=1). From there it inductively follows that with probabilty one T will move any number of steps up.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are we supposed prove T is finite as before proving its expectation is finite? That seems strange considering finite expectation implies finite as

Comment: T is not *always* finite, it is only finite with probability 1. It is therefore not "immediately obvious" that it should follow that E[T] is finite. Theorems like the proposition you mentioned basically establish this or similar "obvious" properties.

Comment: Thanks KT. I think I get you now. Is the induction really on b? I think it is on n

Comment: On b, of course. Perhaps "induction" here sounds like too much. It is just the reasoning that if T will eventually move one step up with probability 1, then it will eventually move b steps up with probability 1.

Comment: KT., not sure I understand. Is this right: 'I have to show the assumption of the proposition holds for $b=1$ (using induction on the n there) then show said assumption holds for $b=k$ given that it holds for $b=k+1$ (using induction on the n there)' ?

Comment: No. Induction is over b. Using the method shown in the link you can show that T will move one step up with probability 1 (i.e. T is finite for b=1). From there on it is easy to show that the same must hold for b=2,3,4,... the latter generalization is the "induction" part.

Comment: However, I just discovered that in general P(X is finite) = 1 does not always necessarily imply that E[X] is finite. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/731017/finite-in-probability-implies-finite-expectation

Hence, although it is easy to show that in your case P(T is finite)=1, this is not enough.

Comment: ..........................which is what I was saying

Comment: Not sure that changes your answer. I should still prove the assumption of the proposition inductively on b right?

Comment: Btw KT., the proof in the link assumes the assumption. It doesn't prove the assumption. I think. Does your suggestion change?

Comment: Once again - it is fairly straightforward to show that P(T is finite) = 1. The proof in the link is one example of how to do that. You could also use the law of large numbers (which tells you that X_n grows as n*(n-q) with probability 1). This, however, does not yet immediately imply E(T) is finite. Perhaps you would need to write out explicit probabilities of T reaching b to show the latter (which is somewhat annoying).

Comment: Sorry KT. Edited post forgot to mention. The proof given in the pdf link proves $E[T] < \infty$. Should I use that kind of proof to prove $E[T] < \infty$? I think I just have to show that $T$ satisfies the assumptions of the proposition?

Comment: The first assumption you want to use does not hold in general. Indeed, it is not true that for any realization F_n of n steps you will be able to reach within N steps with at least a fixed probability. If you happened to descend low enough you won't always need at most N steps to reach b from there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32867/discussion-between-kt-and-bclc).